# Check whether combination of values from multiple dataframe's columns follow given pattern (rules) - pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe df_pattern containing pattern(rules):

```
df_pattern = pd.DataFrame({'SiteId': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
            'ZoneId': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]})
```

That pattern must be followed by another dataframe:

```
df_checked = pd.DataFrame({'SiteId': [6, 5, 7, 4, 8, 7, 5, 8, 6],
            'ZoneId': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]})
```

***SiteId*** values 4,5,6 must be only associated with value 1 (***ZoneId***) and 7,8 with value 2.
I'd love to find rows which doesnt follow this pattern. Therefore result should like this:

```
index SitedId ZoneId
3     4       2
7     8       1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `df_pattern` create a `pattern` col to tag which one is pattern row,
2. then left join `df_checked`
3. by column `pattern`, we can find which row in `df_checked` is not the pattern row.

```
df_pattern['pattern'] = 1
dfn = pd.merge(df_checked, df_pattern, how='left')
print(dfn.loc[dfn.pattern.isnull(), ['SiteId','ZoneId']])

       SiteId  ZoneId
    3       4       2
    7       8       1

print(dfn)

       SiteId  ZoneId  pattern
    0       6       1      1.0
    1       5       1      1.0
    2       7       2      1.0
    3       4       2      NaN
    4       8       2      1.0
    5       7       2      1.0
    6       5       1      1.0
    7       8       1      NaN
    8       6       1      1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar answer for reference:

```
df_all = df_checked.merge(df_pattern, how='left', indicator=True)

   SiteId   ZoneId     _merge
0       6        1       both
1       5        1       both
2       7        2       both
3       4        2  left_only
4       8        2       both
5       7        2       both
6       5        1       both
7       8        1  left_only
8       6        1       both


df_checked[df_all._merge == 'left_only']

  SiteId    ZoneId
3      4         2 
7      8         1
```